# Changing SPI buffer size on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, spi

Im trying to change buffer size for SPI communication for RPi with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. There is no `/boot/cmdline.txt`. I have added line

```
options spidev bufsiz=8192
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/spidev.conf` but it didnt work. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out on ubuntu file cmdline.txt is located at /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
editing this file changes spi buffer size.

Comment: This is the same location as the current Rpi OS version ("bookworm").